# access fields in setCallback returned result

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

In SetCallback I return Opportunity

I get the response but variable doesnot give exact field value.

```
      action.setCallback(this,function (a){
            var Opty = a.getReturnValue();

            console.log(Opty);
            console.log( Opty.StageName == "Initiation");
      }
```

**Output is**

[image]

Comment: It should return true, can you please post your component code as well as Apex code.

Comment: can you try this , to check what value are getting in log.. console.log( Opty.StageName + Opty.StageName == "Initiation");